# Is it possible to use (system -> Data transfer -> import) products csv programmatically

Tags: magento2, import, import-products

I want to create a cron module (in Magento) to download some CSV to the import folder, and then use the (system -> Data transfer -> import) feature to add/replace products programmatically, but not using backend interface to use (system -> Data transfer -> import).

Does anyone know how to trigger (system -> Data transfer -> import) in programming or any API to do that?

remarks: Most of the creating product's solution on the internet is using hardcode e.g categories id, attribute value id, i don't want to use such solution

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we are using this module to do export and import via cron. You can refer to it. Hope it can help you to solve this problem
https://marketplace.magento.com/firebear-importexport.html